# attempt to select less than one element in integerOneIndex

Tags: r, continuous, discretization

I am trying to use mdlp package in R to discretize the continuous data that I created as an example.

```
A=cbind(2,3,6,7,29,56,192,1256)
A=t(A)
mdlp(A)
```

But I received the following error

```
Error in cutp[[i]] <- cuts1 : 
  attempt to select less than one element in integerOneIndex
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

Can anyone tell me what is the problem? How come a package cannot handle such a short length of the sequence?

Comment: Is this you want `arules::discretize(A, breaks = 2)` ? , also `mdlp` resides in `discretize` package

Comment: Thanks. I know I installed the discretize package already. Can you explain what arulles package does ? what does your command do ? is it the same as mdlp?

Comment: @PKumar, I am looking for a good way to discretize the continuous variable it does not have to be mdlp.